# specifying a parameter's default value

Tags: sql, vb.net

When executing this stored proc on vb.net and leaving the purchase textbox blank to make it null when updating. but it returns error saying String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. Any suggestions to make the code work would be much appreciated.

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateEquipmentProfile

    (
    @OE_ID          varchar(11) =   NULL,
    @OE_Category        char(3)     =   NULL,
    @OE_SubCategory     char(3)     =   NULL,
    @OE_Name            varchar(35) =   NULL,
    @OE_User            varchar(35) =   NULL,
    @OE_Brand           varchar(15) =   NULL,
    @OE_Model           varchar(35) =   NULL,
    @OE_Specs           varchar(1000)   =   NULL,
    @OE_SerialNo        varchar(35) =   NULL,
    @OE_PropertyNo      varchar(35) =   NULL,
    @OE_MacAddress      varchar(100)    =   NULL,
    @OE_Static_IP       varchar(15) =   NULL,
    @OE_Vendor          varchar(35) =   NULL,
    @OE_PurchaseDate        smalldatetime   =   NULL,
    @OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear   int     =   NULL,
    @OE_WarrantyStatus      char(2)     =   NULL,
    @OE_Status          varchar(15) =   NULL,
    @OE_Dept_Code       char(3)     =   NULL,
    @OE_Location_Code       char(8)     =   NULL,
    @OE_Remarks         varchar(1000)   =   NULL
    )

    AS

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tblOfficeEquipmentProfile WHERE OE_ID=@OE_ID)

    UPDATE tblOfficeEquipmentProfile    SET
    OE_Category         =@OE_Category,
    OE_SubCategory      =@OE_SubCategory,
    OE_Name         =@OE_Name,
    OE_User         =@OE_User,
    OE_Brand            =@OE_Brand,
    OE_Model            =@OE_Model,
    OE_Specs            =@OE_Specs,
    OE_SerialNo         =@OE_SerialNo,
    OE_PropertyNo       =@OE_PropertyNo,
    OE_MacAddress       =@OE_MacAddress,
    OE_Static_IP        =@OE_Static_IP,
    OE_Vendor           =@OE_Vendor,
    OE_PurchaseDate     =@OE_PurchaseDate,
    OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear    =@OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear,
    OE_WarrantyStatus       =@OE_WarrantyStatus,
    OE_Status           =@OE_Status,
    OE_Dept_Code        =@OE_Dept_Code,
    OE_Location_Code        =@OE_Location_Code,
    OE_Remarks          =@OE_Remarks

    WHERE OE_ID=@OE_ID
    GO
```

VB.NET CODE

```
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = sqlconn.CreateCommand
    sqlconn.Open()
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.CommandText = "UpdateEquipmentProfile"

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 11, "oeq-su-999")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Category", SqlDbType.Char, 3, "COM")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_SubCategory", SqlDbType.Char, 3, "SU")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 35, "adminpmis01")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_User", SqlDbType.VarChar, 35, "Ivan")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Brand", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15, "DELL")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Model", SqlDbType.VarChar, 35, "optiplex")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Specs", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1000, "dualcore")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_SerialNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 35, "sgh5960")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_PropertyNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 35, "j7h7h6g6f2")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_MacAddress", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100, "j7h7:h6g6f2")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Static_IP", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15, "192.168.1.5")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Vendor", SqlDbType.VarChar, 35, "ADWAYS")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_PurchaseDate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear", SqlDbType.Int)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_WarrantyStatus", SqlDbType.Char, 2, "IN")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15, "Good")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Dept_Code", SqlDbType.Char, 3, "ADM")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Location_Code", SqlDbType.Char, 8, "ADM_OFC")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Remarks", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1000, "ACTIVE")
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_ID").Value = txtOEID.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_Category").Value = cmbCategory.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_SubCategory").Value = cmbSubCategory.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_Name").Value = txtName.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_User").Value = txtUser.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_Brand").Value = cmbBrand.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_Model").Value = cmbModel.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_Specs").Value = txtSpecs.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_SerialNo").Value = txtSerialNo.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_PropertyNo").Value = txtPropertyNo.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_MacAddress").Value = txtMacAddress.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_Static_IP").Value = txtStaticIp.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_Vendor").Value = txtVendor.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_PurchaseDate").Value = txtPurchaseDate.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear").Value = txtWarrantyInclusiveYear.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_WarrantyStatus").Value = txtWarrantyStatus.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_Status").Value = txtStatus.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_Dept_Code").Value = cmbDeptCode.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_Location_Code").Value = cmbLocationCode.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_Remarks").Value = txtRemarks.Text
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("Successfully Updated Equipment Profile")
    sqlconn.Close()
```

Comment: You'll need to pass in NULL (perhaps DB.Null even), not a string - even if it is an empty string. The ability to call the SP proc with named parameters (which is required to truly utilize "default values") will depend upon how the SP is called - which is not shown. However, in both cases, the client-side needs to know to map "" to NULL (or "not specified") as appropriate.

Comment: @user2246674 how to pass the NULL VALUE sir? i tried putting .value = DBNULL.Value on vb.net something like that but still doesnt work sir

Comment: If txtPurchaseDate.Text is not empty, then bind the parameter, otherwise, just do nothing.

Comment: how would i bind the parameter  sir @LouieBao

Answer (score 1):

Because the parameter has the default value of NULL:

```
 @OE_PurchaseDate        smalldatetime   =   NULL,
```

you are not forced to pass in a value if there is no value to pass in

For example:

```
if txtPurchaseDate.Text <> "" then
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_PurchaseDate").Value = txtPurchaseDate.Text
```

Comment: I would use `TryParse` instead, to ensure an invalid DateTime isn't passed into the stored proc, causing it to fail.  `if DateTime.TryParse(txtPurchaseDate.Text, d) Then`, with `d` being a `DateTime`.  Then they could assign `d` to the parameter if the conversion succeeds (it will fail on an empty string/null string).

Comment: @Tim, agree, but if there is a proper calendar control on the UI, then it is probably alright?

Comment: If being the operative word.  Since all we have of the OP's code is a TextBox, we don't know what the UI is.  In any event, I like to err on the side of caution - if a user can do something silly, they will :)

Comment: OF course, since OP stated below that they are using VS 2003, my above point is mute in the context of their issue :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim d as DateTime
DateTime.TryParse(txtPurchaseDate.Text, d)
```

Then pass `d` to your stored proc call.

```
cmd.Parameters("@OE_PurchaseDate").Value = d
```

Comment: how can i pass d to stored proc sir? im kinda new to parameters

Comment: supply your vb code that you are using to call the stored proc and I can show you

Comment: I altered my answer - please try it

Comment: It would be good to note that if `TryParse` fails, `d` will be `DateTime.MinValue` (01/01/0001), which is not the same as null and could lead to data problems down the road if OP is expecting null values.

Comment: blue line error on 'DateTime.TryParse' sir. im using vb.net 2003

Comment: 2003 = .NET 1.1.  `DateTime.TryParse` is 2.0 and later.

Comment: That's a shame you are using 2003 - there are some nice features in 2.0 I recommend you upgrade at some point.